# 2d shooter mouse follow issues. Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d shooter but I have run into an issue. When my character flips its scale to -1 when going left the rotation of the weapon hold inverts away from the cursor. Here is the mouse follow code I have in case it is needed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



    public float offset;



    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);


    }
```

Any help is use full.

Comment: Please include how you are flipping the scale. I'm assuming you're flipping only the x component but that's only an assumption.

Comment: I am flipping it on X

Comment: It is still inverted when flipped

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243913/rotating-a-gun-while-flipping-it-in-unity

Comment: I really suggest not doing the 'flipX Scale' method for it really messes up some of your gameObject's functionality like direction, colliders, etc. If you want to achieve something like making the sprite look in a different direction, try flipping the Sprite/Image component only, not the whole gameObject itself: `playersprite.flipX = true` something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mathf.Sign` to take the sign of the x scale into account when calculating the rotation. You will use it to negate x component of the rotation and the angle of rotation itself when the scale is flipped:

```
Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) 
        - transform.position;
float scaleSign = Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x);
float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x * scaleSign) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, (rotZ + offset) * scaleSign );
```

Comment: Sorry but I think I may be doing something wrong as it is still pointing away from the cursor. is there anything I still might be missing?

Comment: @BluChikin I think I got it now. Please try this latest edition.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code.

```
        if (rotZ < -90f || rotZ > 90f)
        {
            if (playerGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0f)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (180f, 0f, rotZ); 
            }
            else if (playerGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 180f)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (180f, 180f, -rotZ); 
            }
        }
```

The full thing would be like this

```
    public float offset;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

        if (rotZ < -90f || rotZ > 90f)
        {
            if (playerGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0f)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (180f, 0f, rotZ); 
            }
            else if (playerGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 180f)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (180f, 180f, -rotZ); 
            }
        }
    }
```

This code changes the way you are rotating the gun if the player is flipped.